# no MousePosition() while using FullScreen() in ol3 map

Tags: mouse-position

The problem is: the MousePosition() is working and shown. But in FullScreen it's not!? 
I tried Rotate() and ScaleLine(). Both are working in FullScreen() but i never saw any coordinates.

I'm using it like this:

```
var mousePosition0 = new ol.control.MousePosition({
    coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(3),
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    className: 'custom-mouse-position',
    target: document.getElementById('mouse-position'),
    undefinedHTML: '&nbsp;'
});
map.addControl (mousePosition0);
```

I'm using a DIV-element (mpb) around the DIV which is showing the coordinates. I did that to change its position ... like followes:

```
<div id="pframe" class="pframe">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="mpb">
        <div id="mouse-position">shows the coordinates</div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Any hints, suggestions or are there more details needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ol3, the full screen option is for div map only.

You can follow one of the following options:

1. You can insert div mpb inside div map.
2. Use browser inbuilt full screen option like f12.

You can check the code of this [Closest Distance Map in OL3](http://geospatialearth.in/ol3/main/) to see how to get mouse position in full screen mode.

Comment: I used option #1 cause i already know option #2.

it took me a moment but by using another div as a wrapper it worked for me!

Thank you!